# Regular Expressions in NodeJS: Only split() if next character is not a dot

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

The following helps me to split a string:

```
  var separators = ['\\\.', '\\\(', '\\\)', ':', '\\\?', '\\\!', '\\\"', '\\\n'];
  var tokens = someString.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'));
```

Whenever there is a `.` the string is split. However, my document sometimes contains `...` and when that is the case, I would like to **not** to split the string three times, but only after the last dot.

To illustrate, consider the following sentences:

```
(1) I saw the dog. But I didn't care.
(2) The duck didn't see it coming...
```

(1) should give me an array with two sentences.

(2) should give me an array with one sentence.

As of right now, (2) would give me an array with 3 sentences, as there are three dots.

Is there any way for me to do this easily?

Comment: People (including myself!) keep misreading the question. Please update it with example input and output when you have a `.`, a `..`, and a `...` in the string.

Comment: without lookbehind it will be a hard task

Comment: @T.J.Crowder updated.

Answer (score 3):

you can use boundaries `\b` like this `/\b\s*\.\s*\b/g`

`\s*` mean zero or more spaces

`\.` match the `.` symbol

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/P7HOVM/5)

Demo Output

```js
const re = /\b\s*\.\s*\b/g;
const str = ` I saw the dog. But I didn't care.`;
const str2 = `The duck didn't see it coming...`;
const str3 = `This is not....the end. this is. not the beginning Linking Park`;

var found = str.split(re);
var found2 = str2.split(re);
var found3 = str3.split(re);

console.log(found);
console.log(found2);
console.log(found3);
```

Answer (score 0):

for the string with more than two `.` use `/([.]{2,})/g;`

```js
const re = /([.]{2,})/g;
const str = `abc...def.ghi`;

var found = str.match(re);

console.log(found);
```

after that

you can use the following pattern `/([^.]+)/g`

example in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Uw1Pq9/1)

```js
const re = /([^.]+)/g;
const str = `abc.def.ghi`;

var found = str.match(re);
console.log(found);
```

Comment: This splits on `...`. From the question *"However, my document sometimes contains '...' and when that is the case, I would like to **not** split the string."*